# Why different assembling code generated? Which is better?

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, optimization, x86-64

```cpp
#include <cstdint>

uint64_t hr1(const uint64_t x, const bool a, const int n) noexcept
{
    if (a) {
        return x | (a << n);
    }
    return x;
}

uint64_t hr2(const uint64_t x, const bool a, const int n)
{
    return x | ((a ? 1ull : 0) << n);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/gy_65H

```
hr1(unsigned long, bool, int):
  mov rax, rdi
  test sil, sil
  jne .L4
  ret
.L4:
  mov ecx, edx
  mov esi, 1
  sal esi, cl
  movsx rsi, esi
  or rax, rsi
  ret
hr2(unsigned long, bool, int):
  mov ecx, edx
  movzx esi, sil
  sal rsi, cl
  mov rax, rsi
  or rax, rdi
  ret
```

Why clang and gcc cannot optimize first function as second?

Comment: Have you proven that they are equivalent?

Comment: `hr1` also does its shifts int 32-bit, not 64-bit like `hr2`

Comment: What are the optimization settings?

Comment: @AlexF I think the compiler can assume that `a` is either 0 or 1 because anything else would be due to undefined behavior.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews "-O2" and "-O3" produces the same.

Comment: I assume your first example should have been `if (a) { return x | 1ull << n; } ...` to be proper.

Comment: the two functions are not remotely the same.  with that godbolt setup lurkers suggestion still results in different code with a test up front on hr1 and to figure that out you need to dig into the compiler sources.

Answer (score 5):

The functions do not have identical behavior. In particular in the first one `a` will undergo integer promotion to `int` in `a << n`, so that the shift will have undefined behavior if `n >= std::numeric_limits<int>::digits` (typically 31).

This is not the case in the second function where `a ? 1ull : 0` will result in the common type of `unsigned long long`, so that the shift will have well-defined behavior for all non-negative values `n < std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::digits` (typically 64) which is most likely more than `std::numeric_limits<int>::digits` (typically 31).

You should cast `a` and `1` to `uint64_t` in both shifts to make the code well behaved for all sensible inputs (i.e. `0 <= n < 64`).

---

Even after fixing that the functions do not have equal behavior. The second function will have undefined behavior if `n >= 64` or `n < 0` no matter what the value of `a` is while the first function has well-defined behavior for `a == false`. The compiler must guarantee that this case returns `x` unmodified, no matter how large (or negative) the value of `n` is.

The second function therefore in principle gives the compiler more freedom to optimize since the range of valid input values is much smaller.

Of course, if the function gets inlined (likely), the compiler may use what it knows about the possible range of values in the call arguments for `a` and `n` and optimize further based on that.

This isn't the issue here though, GCC will compile to similar assembly for the first function if e.g.

```
uint64_t hr1(const uint64_t x, const bool a, const int n) noexcept
{
    return a ? x | (uint64_t{1} << n) : x | (uint64_t{0} << n);
}
```

is used (which has the same valid inputs as `hr2`). I don't know which of the two assemblies will perform better. I suppose you will have to benchmark that or wait for some expert on that to show up.

Comment: If you mostly care about compiling for x86 (-64), you can mask `n` to avoid UB.  Compilers know that `shl r64, cl` implements `r64 << (cl&63)` so they can optimize the `&63` into the shift. (ARM shifts saturate the shift count so masking it wouldn't optimize away unless the compiler had value-range info).  In a stand-alone function def, they have to emit asm that works for the non-UB cases.  The only real danger is if the function *does* inline and gcc propagates value-range assumptions that aren't true to other parts of the caller. i.e. assuming that `n<=63` when it might not be.

Answer (score 3):

**Both ways look over-complicated (and the first one is buggy for n>=32)**.  To promote a bool to a uint64_t 0 or 1, just use `uint64_t(a)` or a C-style cast.  You don't need `a ? 1ull : 0`.

The simple branchless way is probably good, unless you expect `a` to be highly predictable (e.g. usually one way, or correlated with earlier branching.  Modern TAGE predictors use recent branch history to index the BHT / BTB.)

```
uint64_t hr2(uint64_t x, bool a, int n) {
    return x | (uint64_t(a) << n);
}
```

If you want to make this more complicated to avoid UB when `n` is out of range, write your C++ to wrap the shift count the same way x86 shift instructions do, so the compiler doesn't need any extra instructions.

```
#include <limits>
uint64_t hr3(uint64_t x, bool a, int n) {
    using shiftwidth = decltype(x);
    const int mask = std::numeric_limits<shiftwidth>::digits - 1;
    // wrap the count to the shift width to avoid UB
    // x86 does this for free for 32 and 64-bit shifts.
    return x | (shiftwidth(a) << (n & mask));
}
```

Both versions compile identically for x86 (because the simple version has to work for all inputs without UB).

This compiles decently if you have BMI2 (for single-uop variable-count shifts on Intel), otherwise it's not great.  (https://agner.org/optimize/ and https://uops.info/)  But even then there are missed optimizations from GCC:

```
# GCC9.2 -O3 -march=skylake
hr3(unsigned long, bool, int):
        movzx   esi, sil             # zero-extend the bool to 64-bit, 1 cycle latency because GCC failed to use a different register
        shlx    rsi, rsi, rdx        # the shift
        mov     rax, rsi             # stupid GCC didn't put the result in RAX
        or      rax, rdi             # retval = shift | x
        ret
```

This could have been

```
# hand optimized, and clang 9.0 -O3 -march=skylake
   movzx  eax, sil              # mov-elimination works between different regs
   shlx   rax, rax, rdx         # don't need to take advantage of copy-and-shift
   or     rax, rdi
   ret
```

**It turns out that clang9.0 actually does emit this efficient version with `-O3 -march=skylake` or `znver1`.  ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/i3drsR)).**

**This is cheap enough (3 uops) it's not worth branching for, except to break the data dependency on `n` in case `x` and `a` are likely to be ready earlier than `n`.**

But without BMI2, the shift would take a `mov ecx, edx`, and a 3-uop (on Intel SnB-family) `shl rax, cl`.  AMD has single-uop variable-count shifts even for the legacy versions that do write flags (except when CL=0 and they have to leave FLAGS unmodified; that's why it costs more on Intel).  GCC is still dumb and zero-extends in place instead of into RAX.  Clang gets it right (and takes advantage of the unofficial calling convention feature where narrow function args are sign or zero-extended to 32-bit so it can use `mov` instead of `movzx`)  https://godbolt.org/z/9wrYEN

Clang compiles an `if()` to branchless using CMOV, so that's significantly worse than the simple version that uses `uint64_t(a) << n`.  It's a missed optimization that it doesn't compile my hr1 the same as my hr3; they

GCC actually branches and then uses `mov reg, 1` / shl / or for the `if` version.  Again it *could* compile it the same as hr3 if it chose to.  (It can assume that `a=1` implies `n<=63`, otherwise the `if` version would have shift UB.)

---

**The missed optimization in both is failure to use `bts`, which implements `reg |= 1<<(n&63)`**

Especially for gcc after branching so it knows its shifting a constant `1`, the tail of the function should be `bts rax, rdx` which is 1 uop with 1c latency on Intel, 2 uops on AMD Zen1 / Zen2.  GCC and clang *do* know how to use `bts` for the simple case of a compile-time-constant `a=1`, though: https://godbolt.org/z/rkhbzH

There's no way that I know of to hand-hold GCC or clang into using `bts` otherwise, and I wouldn't recommend inline-assembly for this unless it's in the most critical inner loop of something and you're prepared to check that it doesn't hurt other optimizations, and to maintain it.  i.e. just don't.

But ideally GCC / clang would do something like this when BMI2 isn't available:

```
# hand optimized, compilers should do this but don't.
        mov     rax, rdi           # x
        bts     rdi, rdx           # x | 1<<(n&63)
        test    sil, sil
        cmovnz  rax, rdi           # return a ? x_with_bit_set : x;
        ret
```

Doesn't require BMI2, but still only 4 uops on Broadwell and later.  (And 5 uops on AMD Bulldozer / Zen).  Critical path latencies:

- `x` -> retval: 2 cycles (through (MOV and BTS) -> CMOV) on Broadwell and later.  3 cycles on earlier Intel (2 uop cmov) and on any AMD (2 uop BTS).
- `n` -> retval: same as `x` (through BTS -> CMOV).
- `a` -> retval: 2 cycles (through TEST -> CMOV) on Broadwell and later, and all AMD.  3 cycles on earlier Intel (2 uop cmov).

This is pretty obviously better than what clang emits for any version without `-march=skylake` or other BMI2, and even more better than what GCC emits (unless branchy turns out to be a good strategy).

---

#### One way that clang will use BTS:

If we mask the shift count for the branchy version, then clang will actually branch, and on the branch where the if body runs it implements it with `bts` as I described above.  https://godbolt.org/z/BtT4w6

```
uint64_t hr1(uint64_t x, bool a, int n) noexcept
{
    if (a) {
        return x | (uint64_t(a) << (n&63));
    }
    return x;
}
```

clang 9.0 -O3 (without `-march=`)

```
hr1(unsigned long, bool, int):
        mov     rax, rdi
        test    sil, sil
        je      .LBB0_2            # if(a) {
        bts     rax, rdx               # x |= 1<<(n&63)
.LBB0_2:                           # }
        ret
```

So if branchy is good for your use-case, then this way of writing it compiles well with clang.

---

#### These stand-alone versions might end up different after inlining into a real caller.

For example, a caller might save a MOV instruction if it can have the shift count `n` already in CL.  Or the decision on whether to do if-conversion from an `if` to a branchless sequence might be different.

Or if `n` is a compile-time constant, that means we don't need BMI2 to save uops on the shift anymore; immediate shifts are fully efficient on all modern CPUs (single uop).

And of course if `a` is a compile time constant then it's either nothing to do or optimizes to a `bts`.

---

Further reading: see the performance links in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for more about how to decide if asm is efficient by looking at it.